# DataReader and subprocedure issue

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, static-variables

My first subprocedure searches a database using a parameter and returns fields to a form.  My 2nd subprocedure which is supposed to cycle to the next reader isn't working as planned.

I was told all I would have to do is make the connection, dReader, and cmd strings static variables, and then just call the reader again to cycle to the next record in the 2nd subprocedure...

I'm getting this error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  When I press the first button, the search works and it pulls up the first record, but when I click the 'Next' record button and it goes to the 2nd subprocedure, when it gets to the `if(dReader.HasRows)` it gets an error which says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" How can I get dReader to pickup on reading rows from where it left off in the first subprocedure?

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#"%>

<script runat = "server" >

static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn;
static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd;
static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dReader;
protected void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtFirst.Text = "";
    txtMiddle.Text = "";
    txtLast.Text = "";
    txtAddress1.Text = "";
    txtAddress2.Text = "";
    txtCity.Text = "";
    txtState.Text = "";
    txtZip.Text = "";
    var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Server=IDEA-PC\LOCALHOST;Database=Student;Trusted_Connection=True;");

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblSearch.Text = "Connection Error! " + ex;
    }

    var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, PostalCode from dbo.Person INNER JOIN dbo.Address on dbo.Person.StudentID = dbo.Address.StudentID " +
        "where dbo.Person.FirstName LIKE @Name order by FirstName", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "%" + txtSearch.Text + "%");
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    String s = "";
    if (txtSearch.Text == s)
    {
        lblSearch.Text = "Please enter a name!";

    }
    else
    {
        if (dReader.HasRows)
        {

            dReader.Read();
            txtFirst.Text = dReader["FirstName"].ToString();
            txtMiddle.Text = dReader["MiddleName"].ToString();
            txtLast.Text = dReader["LastName"].ToString();
            txtAddress1.Text = dReader["AddressLine1"].ToString();
            txtAddress2.Text = dReader["AddressLine2"].ToString();
            txtCity.Text = dReader["City"].ToString();
            txtState.Text = dReader["State"].ToString();
            txtZip.Text = dReader["PostalCode"].ToString();
            dReader.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            lblSearch.Text = "No Data Found!";
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}

protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dReader.HasRows)
    {
        dReader.Read();
        txtFirst.Text = dReader["FirstName"].ToString();
        txtMiddle.Text = dReader["MiddleName"].ToString();
        txtLast.Text = dReader["LastName"].ToString();
        txtAddress1.Text = dReader["AddressLine1"].ToString();
        txtAddress2.Text = dReader["AddressLine2"].ToString();
        txtCity.Text = dReader["City"].ToString();
        txtState.Text = dReader["State"].ToString();
        txtZip.Text = dReader["PostalCode"].ToString();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a few mistakes here.  In the code below, the `using` block will dispose the `dReader` when it leave the block

```
  using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

and you can't use the same `dReader` after it has been disposed.

Another issue is that you have `static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dReader;` but inside btnFirst_Click method you are creating the method level `dReader`

I would load the search results to a `DataSet/DataTable` and use that for the UI. You can use [FormView](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/12/aspnet-formview-how-to-use.html) for this.

In the page load, do as below

```
formView.DataSource = dataTable;
formView.DataBind();
```

Comment: That makes sense, because I learned it also disposes of the connection...is there another way that I can rewrite the blocks without the using statements?

Comment: I'm kind of confused myself now...I removed the using blocks but I'm still getting the same error...I'll update my code to what I did

Comment: do as `dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`, don't create method level reader, you need to assign the newly created reader to your static reader

Comment: Nevermind!! I see what you're saying. It's working now :) I just need to figure out how to loop it back to the first record when it's done cycling

Answer (score 0):

In your first button click handler, you use the using block for your SQLDataReader object. At the end of that block, the object is closed. As a result, when you try to use the same object in your second handler, the object is null again.

You can remedy this by using same code as first handler in your second handler to populate the object.